# VB Excel can't Copy and Paste Macro that Pulls the Cell Position

Tags: excel, vba

I have a datasheet that looks like this

**page 1**

Costumer: josef

Id: 12345

I create a form that includes (Costumer and ID) more easily manually. Inside the form I have information.

I have an insert button that delivery the information to specific cells inside the page.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 23 'Get last empty cell in column A
Range("D" & i).Value = TextBox1
'Range("D1").Value = TextBox1
Range("D2").Value = TextBox4
Range("C4").Value = TextBox2
Range("C5").Value = TextBox3
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
       Range("A7").Value = OptionButton1.Caption
       ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
       Range("A7").Value = OptionButton2.Caption
       ElseIf OptionButton3.Value = True Then
       Range("A7").Value = OptionButton3.Caption
       Else
       Range("A7").Value = OptionButton4.Caption
     End If
Unload Me
End Sub
```

My problem is that I need to do the same in page 2 of the worksheet, when I copy and paste the macro to do the same in page 2, I need that values will be realease in the same position but in page 2, but the macro release the date in the same cells of the page 1, if you look the code I’ve set  Value = TextBox1 to “D1, I need a formula that after copy macro and I invoked the form, It paste in the active sheet, Not on the first page like it does right now.
Try placing a counter but that does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

on this picture you will see sheet1 "hoja1" and page1 "pagina 1" and the load form (datos del presupuesto)
[image]

I also have picture 2 with sheet one but page 2 (pagina 2), in this page i copy and paste the same I have in page 1 (macro and everything) and i press insertar button to load the form, when the sistem insert it does it in the 1th page not in the 2 page.

[image]

It should be a formula that can help me when i copy one page and pastes the macros pull all the cell values to the page I am paste all the data.

Comment: What do you call a page??? Is it a sheet? One of those named tabs you click in the bottom of the screen???

Comment: If that's the case, before all `Range` you find in your code, add `Sheet1.`, or `Sheet2.` and so on, representing the sheet you want to add the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to take a range from a specific sheet, use that sheet before the range:

```
Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = TextBox1 'takes cell from first sheet.
Sheet2.Range..... 'takes cell from second sheet.


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range.... 'you get sheets by their names
```

You can also put the sheet into a variable so you keep using it instead of repeating sheet name all over:

```
Dim TargetSheet as Worksheet
Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")

TargetSheet.Range.....
TargetSheet.Range......
TargetSheet.Range......
```

---

So your code could be like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'First thing: select your specific sheet:
    Dim MySheet as Worksheet
    Set MySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TheNameOfYourSheet")

    'Now, before every range or cell, take them FROM that specific sheet
    i = MySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 23 'Get last empty cell in column A

    'Select your pivot cell (don't forget MySheet)
    Dim PivotCell as Range
    Set PivotCell = MySheet.Range("D" & i)

    'Put the value in the pivot
    PivotCell.Value = TextBox1 

    'Now you can start using the offsets (it's really better, as you commented)
    PivotCell.Offset(0,1).Value = TextBox4 'That would be D2 if Pivot is D1

    'I'm not sure if you can use negative offsets, 
    'if not, take the top left cell of your target area as pivot -
    'But there surely will be an error if the offset falls to the left or above A1
    PivotCell.Offset(3, -1).Value = TextBox2 'That is C4 -         
    PivotCell.Offset(4,-1).Value = TextBox3 'C5

    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        PivotCell.Offset(6,-3).Value = OptionButton1.Caption ' A7
    ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        PivotCell.Offset(6,-3).Value = OptionButton2.Caption
    ElseIf OptionButton3.Value = True Then
        PivotCell.Offset(6,-3).Value = OptionButton3.Caption
    Else
        PivotCell.Offset(6,-3).Value = OptionButton4.Caption
    End If

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

One thing EVEN BETTER is to `Name` a cell. In the top left of the Excel screen, there is a text box where the selected cell coordinates are show (like "A1", "B2", ...). If you type a name in that box, you can use that named cell via code like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("NamedCell")
```

Comment: well it is hard to explain but let me show you pictures of what I have.
on this picture you will see sheet1 "hoja1" and page1 "pagina 1" and the load form (datos del presupuesto)

Comment: i found that ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) can work around that, but still i need to like a pivote cell to map the other cells

Comment: Every cell is a `Range`, the `ActiveCell` is a range too. So, you can select your pivot cell from any sheet you like, and offset it. See edit in my answer using that.